# How to zip a python module? e.g caffe

Tags: python, caffe

How do I `zip` a `python` module and its dependencies into a `.zip` file? I want to be able to import the module then on a different host by just importing the `.zip` file.

Comment: Using `zip` command? Read this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html. Compress .py and .pyc files together.

Comment: Python can import zip-files. What error do you get when trying?

Comment: My answer was deleted for containing links so I am posting this on here. I found this article, which explains it in great detail. https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2012/11/23/bundling-up-distributable-python-package-libraries-using-pip-and-zip/